# Open file don't store the first line in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv with some data and I want to made a dictionary in Python.

I do this

```
with open("file.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        dictionary= dict(x.rstrip().split(',', 1) for x in f)
print(dictionary)
```

but althougth the file is

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
```

I only achieve this

```
{'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```

why is missing the first line?

Comment: You are recreating the dictionary for each line in the file.  I can't imagine how you even got two dict elements out of it, either your code or your data differs from what you posted here.

Comment: Side-note: If you're parsing CSV, perhaps use [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @jasonharper: They exhaust the rest of the file in the first iteration of the loop (because it's consumed to construct the `dict`), so it doesn't actually recreate it.

Comment: is there any possibility for your data file to have rows with duplicated key like `a, 1 ... a, 4`?

Answer (score 1):

The `dict` constructor doesn't use the `line` in the `for` loop - it consumes the entire file in its constructor. That first line is ignored and when the loop comes back to the top, the file is exhausted and it exits.

```
with open("file.csv") as f:
    dictionary= dict(x.rstrip().split(',', 1) for x in f)
print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over `f` twice. First you do:

```
for line in f:
```

which sets `line` to the first line of the file. Then within that loop, you use the list comprehension:

```
x.rstrip().split(',', 1) for x in f
```

This reads the remaining lines of `f`, and passes the resulting list to the `dict()` constructor. But since the outer loop read the first line, it's not included in the dictionary.

Then it goes back to the top of the outer loop. Since the file has been read completely, that loop ends.

The solution, as others have pointed out, is to get rid of the outer loop.

```
with open("file.csv") as f:
    dictionary= dict(x.rstrip().split(',', 1) for x in f)
print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something very complicated, you can do the same, simply with `csv` module.

```
with open("file.csv", 'r') as f:            # 'r' > read only
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')   # I am not sure if delimiter is obligatory
    file = dict([x for x in reader])        # This make a list of list with reader and then it is turned into a dictionary
return file
```

For better undersanting:

```
file = dict([x for x in reader])
```

Is the same as:

```
file = []
for x in reader:
    file.append(x)
file = dict(file)
```

Or:

```
file = {}
for x in reader:
    file[x[0]] = x[1]
```